# How can I batch remove trailing silence from audio files

Tags: ableton-live, samples, strip-silence

I'm working on a sample pack of small audio files. I create & record the samples into Ableton Live & for most of them that works fine as they are tied to the BPM, so I can just cut them to the beat. For some of the samples, however, I'd like them to be as short/small as possible. Is there a way that I can batch trim the samples so that all silence at the end is removed? Either directly inside Ableton or as a program that I can just run on a folder. The samples are in `.wav` format

Comment: Have you tried searching for silence removers? Is the silence noise-floor silence or zero amplitude silence?

Comment: I did look for a little while but could not find anything. i think anything below -60dB will be fine to remove. some samples contain some reverb so that should eventually trail off. I don't need the whole tail for that though like down to the very quiet parts at the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the following piece of python code:

```
"""Bulk trim silence from all wav files in the folder of this script."""

import os, glob
import numpy as np
import soundfile as sf

# Noise floor in dB
NOISE_FLOOR = -60

# Trim silence from start?
TRIM_START = True

# Trim silence from end?
TRIM_END = True

# Padding to apply around detected edge of silence
PADDING = 32

epsilon = 10**(NOISE_FLOOR/20)


def process(filename):
    # Load the wav file
    data, samplerate = sf.read(filename, always_2d=True)
    # Find indices of samples above noise floor
    indices = (np.abs(data) >= epsilon).any(axis=1).nonzero()[0]
    # Trim silence (if it found any non-silent samples)
    if len(indices) > 1:
        # Find start and end index to trim (+/- padding)
        start = max(0, indices[0] - PADDING) if TRIM_START else 0
        end = min(len(data), indices[-1] + PADDING) if TRIM_END else len(data)
        trim = data[start: end]
    else:
        trim = data
    # Write trimmed wave to subfolder called 'trimmed' with the same file name
    sf.write(os.path.join('trimmed', os.path.basename(filename)), trim, samplerate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Prepare output directory
    os.makedirs('trimmed', exist_ok=True)
    # Find and process all wav files
    wav_files = glob.glob("*.wav")
    for i, filename in enumerate(wav_files):
        print(f"{i}/{len(wav_files)}: {filename}")
        try:
            process(filename)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Trimming failed!")
            print(ex)
```

this will remove trailing silence from all files in a folder, and place them in a folder called trimmed

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Ableton Live, so I'm not sure if you can automatically strip silence in it, but I recently created a small exe for Windows that does just that - it removes any samples below a given threshold (in dBFS) and allows you to pad the resulting blocks of samples (i.e. leave some leading/trailing silence).
It's called SiRemX (Pronounced "sai·rem ex" - **si**lence **rem**over - Smart, eh?) - I've tested it many times, and it works great, but there are currently some... *minor* limitations:

1. It currently only works with 16 bit & 32 bit(float) stereo WAVE files with simple headers.
2. As it writes NO `AppData` on the computer, the processed samples are held in the RAM, so it won't process large files (e.g. It processed a 3 minute 192k 32 bit(float) perfectly, but wouldn't process a 6-minute version due to memory problems (it reports any issues clearly, if it has any, so you know exactly what happened)).
3. It's a Windows `.exe` application, with a console-based UI, so it only works on Windows systems.
4. It still has some small UI issues, and you may need to `Run as Administrator` if you want to *overwrite* any files.

Other than that, it works perfectly. If you want to try it, it's on my GDrive - [SiRemX](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o3NbLuaAmJQwK8bXYHkt-rB4wGV-qBBT/view?usp=sharing). I'll update it now and then, when I'm bored.

Answer (score 0):

you might be already done with that but anyways...
To me it sounds like a job for the "Gate" audio effect in Ableton.
Also the "remove ambience" Preset from the Multiband Dynamics audio effect should work.
Learned that trick from a "Virtual Riot" producer tutorial - since bass music ofthen relies on heavily processed sounds, whitch often produces ringing tails and stuff - so you got to clean that shi* up all the time... but you get used to it ^^

Comment: that's not what I want, I'm looking to remove silence from files, not from the signal in an audio track. I forgot to post the code I ended up using here which was provided to me by a friend!

Answer (score 0):

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove
Remove silence from the beginning, middle or end of the audio.